# How web.xml, servlet-mapping.url-pattern and maven-ear-plugin contextRoot param connect?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I would like to put together a REST service with Jersey and I'm totally lost among the parameters I mentioned in the title. And when I deploy my stuff, it doesn't work. I can't hit the controller.

I would like to achieve that I can deploy multiple EAR files each one contains a single WAR file, which is the REST endpoint.

For example:

- http://localhost/applicationrestservice1/restapi/Module/getAllModule
- http://localhost/applicationrestservice2/restapi/Other/getStuff

Where applicationrestservice1 and 2 are totally different applications placed in separated ear/war files.

In my case:

- ApplicationService1 is a war file placed in Application1.ear file and responsible for providing REST Api service via http://localhost/applicationrestservice1/ url.
- ApplicationService2 is a war file placed in Application2.ear file and responsible for providing REST Api service via http://localhost/applicationrestservice2/ url.

So, the question: how the following parameters are represented in the url?

- web.xml - `<servlet-mapping><url-pattern>`
- maven-ear-plugin - `<webModule><contextRoot>`
- @Path placed over the class

The server is WildFly 10. Jersey version is 2.25.1. What other info is needed?

I have been searching for this information for a while but the found stuff raises more questions than give answers.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Digital Library - Metadata Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Digital Library - Metadata Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <modules>
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>RESTApi</artifactId>
                    <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                </webModule>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```java
@Path("/Module")
public class ModuleEndpoint implements ModuleEndpointInterface {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getAllModules")
    public Response getAllModules() {

        return Response.status(200)
                .entity("getAllModules")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined `/restapi` and `/Module/getAllModules`... Where did you try to point `/applicationrestservice1`?

Comment: Please, see my update question.

Comment: To be clear, you want to deploy multiple EAR files, each containing one EAR file?

Comment: I want to deploy multiple EAR files, each one contains a WAR file (REST endpoint). I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Some info taken [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqny/index.html):

> For example, if you want to deploy a resource that responds to the URI
> path template
> [http://example.com/myContextRoot/jerseybeans/{name1}/{name2}/](http://example.com/myContextRoot/jerseybeans/%7Bname1%7D/%7Bname2%7D/), you
> must deploy the WAR to a Java EE server that responds to requests to
> the http://example.com/myContextRoot URI, and then decorate your
> resource with the following @Path annotation:
>
> ```
> @Path("/{name1}/{name2}/")
> public class SomeResource {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the URL pattern for the Jersey helper servlet,
> specified in web.xml, is the default:
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>My Jersey Bean Resource\</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/jerseybeans/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> A variable name can be used more than once in the URI path template.

Experimentally, in a weblogic+maven+web.xml scenario, this has confirmed to me the working pattern is:

http://myserver{webModule contextRoot}{web.xml servlet pattern}{Java resource path}

Slashes on the ends of each segment will merge to a single slash.